# Lint Error UnusedId is shown as false positive when we use view binding

Tags: android, lint, android-lint

Previously when we were using findViewById, unused resource id is not shown. However, after enabling view binding, an unused resource id is shown inspite of the id used programmatically using generated view binding classes. Now the lint has thrown this as an error rather than a warning which results in a compilation failure. Please find the below error for reference

`Error: The resource R.id.showMore appears to be unused [UnusedIds]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution to avoid build error, change the severity of the error to the warning in the lint.xml

`<issue id="UnusedIds" severity="warning"/>`

Comment: This is reasonable but I'm also getting lots of false positive warnings about unused methods and method arguments. After a day trying to find a fix or workaround, I'm giving up on view binding.